# Adding a category view to a page

Tags: categories, pages, templates

My categories are set up to display as a grid using the following code (category.php):

```
get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="site-content inner">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">


                    <!-- START OF THE FLEX CONTAINER, THE UNORDERED LIST -->
            <ul class="grid-wrap">


                <!-- WP LOOP STARTS HERE -->
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <!-- LIST ITEM FOR EACH POST -->
                    <li class="grid-item">

                        <!-- FEATURED IMAGE FOR THE POST -->
                        <p>
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'small' ); ?></a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </p>

                        <!-- POST TITLE -->
                        <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>




                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <!-- END OF THE LIST ITEM -->
                    </li>

                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>></div>

            <!-- END OF THE FLEX CONTAINER -->
            </ul>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```

This is fine when filtering by category. I also want to have pages that shows the same category after some intro text, i.e.:

(header)

Some into text here

Grid display of posts
(footer)

These pages will be linked from my header bar, not accessible through filtering. I've got as far as creating a template for each page, but how do I edit the category loop system to display just one category when it's on a page, not on the category's page? (if that makes sense).

I'm a total newbie to php and the wp loop, and am struggling with this. Thanks.

Comment: You say "how do I edit the category loop system to display just one category when it's on a page", which category are you referring to? You want a page to show an specific category?

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear. I want a page (called Basics) to show the following:
Title, 
Text description, 
All posts from 'basic' category, displayed in the grid that my category.php uses

Effectively, I want to show the category, but in a page, after intro text. And so the URL is to the page (.com/basics) NOT to the category (.com/category/basics)

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it...

```
get_header(); ?>
<div id="content" class="site-content inner">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

            <p class="sixhundred">Intro.</p>

                    <!-- START OF THE FLEX CONTAINER, THE UNORDERED LIST -->
            <ul class="grid-wrap">


                <!-- WP LOOP STARTS HERE -->
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) :

                query_posts( "category_name=basic-skills" );

                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <!-- LIST ITEM FOR EACH POST -->
                    <li class="grid-item">

                        <!-- FEATURED IMAGE FOR THE POST -->
                        <p>
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'small' ); ?></a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </p>

                        <!-- POST TITLE -->
                        <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>




                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <!-- END OF THE LIST ITEM -->
                    </li>

                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>></div>

            <!-- END OF THE FLEX CONTAINER -->
            </ul>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
```